# Is it dangerous to always boot with pci=noacpi? What are the effects?

Tags: dual-boot, acpi

I have a HP Pavilion Wave 800-a001no that can only boot with acpi=off or pci=noacpi. If I don't use any of these flags, it just prints an infinite amount of acpi-errors, and won't boot. It's a dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACPI is used to "optimize" your hardware power consumption and to monitor some status. It is best suitable for laptop than for desktop computers, where power management helps save some batteries.

Unfortunately, ACPI and Linux are not the best friends in town and it's not a surprise you have trouble with it. Also, it seems your computer is a desktop, so you better keep acpi off.

Comment: ACPI also controls the fans, so best to turn it off via system settings rather than boot flags in grub